# xsltproc doesn't select elements by name

Tags: xslt

I am trying to transform XHTML using an XSLT stylesheet, but I can't even get a basic stylesheet to match anything.  I'm sure I'm missing something simple.

Here's my XHTML source document (no big surprises):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta name="generator" content=
"HTML Tidy for Windows (vers 25 March 2009), see www.w3.org" />
...
</body>
</html>
```

The actual contents don't matter too much, as I'll demonstrate below.  By the way, I'm pretty sure the document is well-formed since it was created via `tidy -asxml`.

My more complex XPath expressions were not returning any results, so as a sanity test, I'm trying to transform it very simply using the following stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:text>---[</xsl:text>
        <xsl:for-each select="html">
            <xsl:text>Found HTML element.</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:text>]---</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The transform is done via `xsltproc --nonet stylesheet.xsl input.html`, and the output is: "---[]---" (i.e., it didn't find a child element of `html`).  However, if I change the `for-each` section to:

```
<xsl:for-each select="*">
    <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Then I get "---[html]---".  And similarly, if I use `for-each select="*/*"` I get "---[headbody]---" as I would expect.

Why can it find the child element via `*` (with `name()` giving the correct name) but it won't find it using the element name directly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `html` element in your source XML defines a namespace. You have to include it in your match expression and reference it in your `xsl:stylesheet` element:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:text>---[</xsl:text>
        <xsl:for-each select="html:html">
            <xsl:text>Found HTML element.</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:text>]---</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: If I do that, I get "XPath error : Undefined namespace prefix".  Do I need to add something to the stylesheet to say how to resolve the namespace?

Comment: The HTML namespace will need to be declared in the stylesheet as well.  Typically, on the document element of the stylesheet: `<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">`, but it can also be declared on the for-each element: `<xsl:for-each select="html:html" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">`

Comment: Sorry, forgot the namespace reference in the `xsl:stylesheet` element. I updated my answer.

Comment: Works beautifully.  Wish I could omit typing that namespace, though, since more complex XPath expressions like html:html/html:body/html:div[@id='foo']/... is going to get really hard to read.  Sigh... at least it works now.  :)

Answer (score 4):

**Change your stylesheet from**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"> 
    <xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"/> 
    <xsl:template match="/"> 
        <xsl:text>---[</xsl:text> 
        <xsl:for-each select="html"> 
            <xsl:text>Found HTML element.</xsl:text> 
        </xsl:for-each> 
        <xsl:text>]---</xsl:text> 
    </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**to**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
> 
    <xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"/> 
    <xsl:template match="/"> 
        <xsl:text>---[</xsl:text> 
        <xsl:for-each select="x:html"> 
            <xsl:text>Found HTML element.</xsl:text> 
        </xsl:for-each> 
        <xsl:text>]---</xsl:text> 
    </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Explanation**:

The XML document has declared a default namespace: `"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"`, and all unprefixed nodes that descend from the top element declaring this default namespace, belong to this namespace.

On the other side, in XPath any unprefixed name is considered to belong in "no namespace".

Therefore, the `<xsl:for-each select="html">` instruction will select and apply its body to all `html` elements that belong to "no namespace" -- and there are none such in the document -- the only `html` element does belong to the xhtml namespace.

**Solution**:

The the names that belong to a default namespace cannot be referenced unprefixed. Therefore, we need to bind a prefix to the namespace such an element belongs to. If this prefix is `"x:"`, then we can reference any such element **prefixed** with `"x:"`.

Answer (score 1):

A workaround without declaring the namespace, so that the stylesheet accept any namespace:

```
<xsl:template match="*[name()='html']" >
```