# Automate LotusConnections-config.xml modifications with XSL/xsltproc: Nothing replaced by wrong namespace

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, ibm-connections

I just want to replace some XLML element values/attributes in `LotusConnections-config.xml`. Simple example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><!-- Copyright IBM Corp. 2001, 2017  All Rights Reserved.              -->
<config buildlevel="IC6.0_20170314_1305" id="LotusConnections" xmlns="http://www.ibm.com/LotusConnections-config" xmlns:sloc="http://www.ibm.com/service-location" xmlns:tns="http://www.ibm.com/LotusConnections-config" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.ibm.com/LotusConnections-config LotusConnections-config.xsd">

<hostWhitelist enabled="false">
        <domain>admin_replace.com</domain>
</hostWhitelist>
<!-- ... -->
</config>
```

To modify `hostWhitelist` I tried the following *stylesheet*

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <!-- Copies every input node unchanged -->
  <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="hostWhitelist">
       ==XXXXX==
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This simple example shows a fundamental problem: I'd expect to have

```
<hostWhitelist enabled="false">
        <domain>admin_replace.com</domain>
</hostWhitelist>
```

replaced by `==XXXXX==`. But after running `xsltproc --novalid --nonet -o poc-out.xml poc-rules.xml poc-in.xml` I got the same, unmodified input in `poc-out.xml` without any warnings or error messages. After a lot of researching, I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3954686/xsltproc-doesnt-select-elements-by-name). To check if it matches my issue, I tried [the workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12803158/3276634) of replacing `<xsl:template match="hostWhitelist">` by `<xsl:template match="*[name()='hostWhitelist']">` and my substitution worked.

But I don't clearly understand which of the many namespaces from `LotusConnections-config.xml` I need to add, which prefix/suffix to set and why this even matters when `--novalid --nonet` is passed. It seems that `http://www.ibm.com/LotusConnections-config` is the namespace. I tried different combinations, for example

resulting in

```
# xsltproc --novalid --nonet -o poc-out.xml poc-rules.xml poc-in.xml 
compilation error: file poc-rules.xml line 1 element stylesheet
xsltParseStylesheetProcess : document is not a stylesheet
```

I also tried

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xml="http://www.ibm.com/LotusConnections-config" version="1.0">
```

since I'm processing XML, but it raises errors too. The original example from the SO post

gave me no error but doesn't replace anything. The same for `xpath-default-namespace="http://www.ibm.com/LotusConnections-config"` in `<xls:stylesheet` (taken from [here](https://lenzconsulting.com/namespaces-in-xslt/)).

#### My questions are

1. Which of the namespace are required and how (which key) do I set them in my *stylesheet*?
2. Why do I need them, even when no remote/no validation is activated?
3. Do I even have a change to make this work remotely? It seems that those scheme files doesn't exist in IBMs servers any more.

#### What partly worked

`xmlstarlet` has a placeholder `_` [for the default namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44186555/3276634). I assume it's fetched from the input xml file, since it offers drop-in replacement using CLI without *style sheet* file like `xsltproc` does.

```
# xmlstarlet select -t -c "/_:config/_:hostWhitelist" /tmp/lc-checkout/LotusConnections-config.xml 
<hostWhitelist xmlns="http://www.ibm.com/LotusConnections-config" xmlns:sloc="http://www.ibm.com/service-location" xmlns:tns="http://www.ibm.com/LotusConnections-config" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" enabled="false">
       <domain>admin_replace.com</domain>
```

When using the `edit` option, this could be used for substitutions as well as fetching xpath values.

Answer (score 0):

Your XML declares *a default namespace* at the root `config` element as:

```
 xmlns="http://www.ibm.com/LotusConnections-config"
```

This namespace is inherited by all descendants of `config`, unless overriden by another namespace declaration.

Nodes that are in namespace must be addressed by a name using a prefix that is bound to their namespace. Without a prefix, the expression will look for a node in no-namespace - and find nothing, in your example. Try:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:cfg="http://www.ibm.com/LotusConnections-config">
  <!-- Copies every input node unchanged -->
  <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="cfg:hostWhitelist">
       ==XXXXX==
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```